# XPath - Get the 1st XML child without knowing its name

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a slight problem. I am supposed to get the first child of a XML node, but its name is always different. It's like this:

```
<book>
<name>...</name>
//other nodes
</book>
```

The problem is, that the tag is not always "name". There are many variations, like "Name", "title", "Title", "nameOfBook", "book-title", etc. However, its position is always the first child of the "book" node and it always carries the same type of information.

Is there a way, how to access the n-th (1st) child of a node based on its position, but not tag name? I have not much knowledge of the axes, so maybe something like //book::child[1] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either: `//book/*[1]` or `//book/child::*[1]`.